# Kickstrap 2 with stylus bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, stylus, kickstrap

I'm starting using kickstrap (v.2) and I'm wondering how can I use a version of bootstrap "uncompiled" in stylus and not the precompiled themes. Is there a way to do this?

I've created a new project `$ kickstrap new project` and then added bootstrap-stylus via `bower install bootstrap-stylus`. Then in `assets/css` I've changed the @import in `main.styl`

from

```
@import "../themes/kickstrap.css"
```

to

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-stylus/stylus/bootstrap
```

Then if I launch `kicksrap watch` it returns an ident error

```
TypeError: expected string, ident or literal, but got null:null
```

but if you correct this one, another one shows up, over and over again…
So I was wondering if someone knows a way to use kickstrap by compiling bootstrap on his own.

Comment: what did you try so far? what documentation did you use? give some examples.

Comment: Are you referring to Bootstrap.styl, a third-party project?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz yes I was referring to that project